# creating a simple Master Detail (Split View) app for iPad in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, ipad, master-detail

Can anyone help in creating a simple Master Detail (Split View) app for iPad in Xcode 4.2?

I managed to get this done quite easily using previous version of xcode, but in xcode4.2, similar code is giving me the error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'
*** First throw call stack:

i just can't find Master Detail iPad tutorials for xcode 4.2 on the web.

I want to try learning storyboarding and the new features so reverting to a previous version is not really what i want.

Will appreciate any one's help!

Comment: Did you figure this issue out? I've seen several other people with this problem. I've found it only occurs if you bind your master view with more than one item (e.g. numberOfRowsInSection returns > 1).

Comment: Don't know if it answers the question, so I'm posting it as a comment: have you taken a look to this video tut: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhODzF4R3TY&feature=related

Answer (score 0):

On the story board, click on the tableView and change the content to:

> Dynamic Prototypes